# Swift3 - '[String : AnyObject]' is not convertible to '[HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm just new to Swift and have taken over a project written in swift 2.2 with xCode 7.4. I am converting it to xCode 8 and swift3 and have only a single compiler error left. Please help to fix this.

```
'[String : AnyObject]' is not convertible to '[HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]'
```

Here is the offending line of code.

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: dict as! [String : AnyObject] as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any])
```

Would this fix it?

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: dict as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any])
```

Comment: Just replace `AnyObject` with `Any` but I guess you can completely omit the first type cast.

Comment: Can you give me the complete line that would omit the first typecast please?

Comment: Delete `as! [String : AnyObject]`

Comment: Thank you! care to make that an answer so i can credit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnyObject` has been replaced with `Any` in Swift 3 for unspecified dictionary values.

Since `HTTPCookiePropertyKey` is a type alias of `(NS)String` you can cast the type directly

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: dict as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any])
```

Maybe even

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: dict)
```

could work.